Basic Time-sensitive Network (TSN) hardware setup and proof of concept
There's a kernel documentation file that explains the process for testing a couple of TSN endpoints, the first step is setting up receive/transmit queues using ethtool. All of the machines I have tried to run this command on return the same output (below).
$ sudo ethtool -L eno1 rx 1 tx 5
netlink error: Operation not supported

Here is the kernel document that I'm referencing: /kernel-5.10/Documentation/networking/device_drivers/ethernet/ti/cpsw.rst
Is there some special hardware I need on the endpoint side to support TSN?
$ ethtool -i eno1
driver: e1000e
version: 6.5.0-21-generic
firmware-version: 0.1-4
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:00:19.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes

Do I need to have connections to a TSN-capable bridge (switch) before setting up TSN? Further reading down the same kernel document has examples of executing tc using the mqprio queue discipline. That also appears to not be supported by my hardware, as it is returning similar "Not supported" error messages. I would like to know how this is configured, and how I can test my setup to ensure that I have the right hardware for TSN.

I found a document, which proposes a few system requirements. It appears that there are specific endpoint hardware requirements. There are various ethernet controller hardware vendors that support TSN, but the chips need to be installed on the hardware which then can be installed in a desktop, for example.
https://tsn.readthedocs.io/avb.html

System Requirements
This tutorial has been validated on two desktop machines with Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I210 connected back-to-back and Linux kernel version 4.19.

I assume there are several other hardware vendors that support such capability, and encourage others to answer this question more fully. Here's yet another option that appears to support TSN en an embedded application environment.
https://www.cnx-software.com/2021/07/14/lp-am243-dual-gigabit-ethernet-mcu-board-features-ti-sitara-am243x-cortex-r5f-microcontroller/

LP-AM243 dual Gigabit Ethernet MCU board features TI Sitara AM243x
Cortex-R5F microcontroller The few microcontroller boards that get
Ethernet, are often limited to 10 Mbps or 100 Mbps, but the LP-AM243
LaunchPad development kit comes with two Gigabit Ethernet ports
controlled by the newly announced 800 MHz Texas Instruments Sitara
AM243x Cortex-R5F microcontroller with industrial communication and
security features.

